# How can we paint this piechart class?

Tags: java, swing

We can't quite figure out how can make this piechart appear:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;


public class PieChart extends View {

    public PieChart (Model model){
        super(model);
        MyComponent piechart = new MyComponent();
        this.add(piechart);
    }
    public void updateView(){
        repaint();
    }
}

class MyComponent extends JComponent {
    Slice[] slices = {
            new Slice(5, Color.black), new Slice(33, Color.green), new Slice(20, Color.yellow), new Slice(15, Color.red)
    };

    MyComponent() {
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        drawPie((Graphics2D) g, getBounds(), slices);
    }

    void drawPie(Graphics2D g, Rectangle area, Slice[] slices) {
        double total = 0.0D;

        for (int i = 0; i < slices.length; i++) {
            total += slices[1].value;
        }
        double curValue = 0.0D;
        int startAngle = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < slices.length; i++) {
            startAngle = (int) (curValue * 360 / total);
            int arcAngle = (int) (slices[i].value * 360 / total);
            g.setColor(slices[i].color);
            g.fillArc(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height, startAngle, arcAngle);
            curValue += slices[i].value;
        }
    }
}

class Slice {
    double value;
    Color color;
    public Slice(double value, Color color) {
        this.value = value;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

and the class it extends from "view"

```java
import javax.swing.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class View extends JPanel  {
    public Model model;

    public View(Model model)  {
        this.model=model;
        model.addView(this);
    }

    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model=model;
    }

    public Model getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void updateView() {
        repaint();
    }
}
```

and finally the class that calls all views (only the applicable code shown)

```
public class Simulator {

    ....
    private View pieChart;

    public Simulator(int floors, int rows, int places) {
        //initialiseert Model
        floornumber = floors;
        rownumber = rows;
        placenumber = places;

        model=new Model(floornumber,rownumber,placenumber);

        screen=new JFrame("Parkere simulatie");
        screen.setTitle("Parkeer-control Screen");
        screen.setSize(1600, 1000);
        screen.setResizable(false);
        screen.setLayout(null);
        ........

        pieChart = new PieChart(model);
        screen.getContentPane().add(pieChart);
        pieChart.setBounds(840, 300, 300, 300);
    }
}
```

I think the problem is the method paint(). We can't call it from anywhere else but I'm pretty sure we should do it differently because it's a panel instead of a frame. Does anyone know how we can fix this?

Comment: I know, you are using Swing, however JavaFX provides certain charts, e.g. a [PieChart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/PieChart.html). Just wanted to mention this.

Comment: @pzaenger great help ;)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, we now got a piechart going with javaFX :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont show the 'screen' on-screen. (e.g. setVisible) -- it will call paint of children as needed automatically then

again:
make the frame visible and children will be painted by the frame

Comment: Exactly. In Swing you hardly ever call `paint()` yourself. Instead you make something visible (in this case the `screen`) and Swing makes sure it paints all its sub-components.